Adding 2nd OSB flooring to existing shed floor
Have 12x16 barn shed (Tuff Shed) that was already installed when I bought the property in 2017. The joists are made of metal spaced every 24 in and it stands about 12 in above the ground. Recently, I remodeled the shed so that it could be used for arts and crafts. I removed the loft structure, and drywall/insulated the walls and ceilings. I want to install vinyl planks for flooring on top of the OSB. Noticed that OSB has some uneven levels ranging from 1/16 to 3/16. Some edges the OSB has some reduced strength due to water damage. Thinking about placing a 2nd layer of OSB to rectify the unevenness and add sturdiness. Should I use OSB or treated plywood? What thickness and what method should I use to install (glue, screws, etc). Do I need to get screws to go down to the joists or just screw to the bottom OSB?

There's no point to treated plywood. If you have enough moisture to rot the wood  at that location you have other issues.
More OSB is ok, but you could also just skim with a leveling product to feather out the variation. I'd only add more sheathing if you want to improve rigidity in the floor. Screw the new layer into framing and stagger joints for strength and smoothness.


Should I use OSB or treated plywood?

Either could work but I would lean toward 5/8" or 3/4" plywood which will provide a firmer base for the vinyl planks. Since there is some chance of water intrusion you might want to use pressure treated plywood.

What thickness and what method should I use to install (glue, screws,
etc).

Since you have some unevenness in the OSB I think that screws through to the underlying joists would work best. This will allow you to shim under the plywood by running the screws through the shims to even out any gaps.
When the plywood is down you might want to sand and seal the butt joints between sheets. Otherwise the seams may eventually show through the vinyl planks.

3/4" plywood is horrendously expensive and big overkill here.

Good point! 5/8" might make more sense economically but I guess I have a tendency to overbuild.

I would not use OSB or plywood.  I would use 1/4 durock. It comes in 4x8 sheets like plywood.  It is dense yet relatively light.
Lay it perpendicular to the OSB that is there. Use 1 inch multi material screws. and building adhesive like liquid nails. Screwed into the wood, it does not have to be screwed into the joists.
It makes a great base for a good quality ( minimum 5.5mm total thickness) LVP floor.
